# How can I improve my answers for available questions where I'm able to answer them?

Tags: discussion, answers, help-improvement

*Background:* Recently I writing some answers on what I think there was interesting questions waiting someone to answer them addressing problems they're having trouble with, but not all of my answers received well - some of them getting upvotes (even it not so stellar), but another ones are downvoted. The downvoted ones usually posted before the question closed later with various reasons (including dupes).

I don't want to trigger "*meta effect*" here (possibly pushing my existing posts into their oblivion), so there are points I want to ask for:

1. Is there another "hidden rule" for answering other than stated in help center (e.g. "avoid answering possible dupe questions" or "no answering for obvious off-topic questions")?
2. What should I do to improve existing downvoted answers rather than deleting those things? The duplicates sometimes are not fast enough to detect them, so there is a chance to put well-written answer before getting caught & closed thereafter. Also I think finding possible duplicates is part of OP's responsibility to search before asking.
3. Should I change my writing style to be more brief when answering? I feel that some people may not received my posts well due to having "too many details" or "not addressing OP's intent properly to the point".

I'm looking for constructive ways so that I can write answers well without fearing too much about downvotes.

Related questions:

[Are "what can I do to improve this post" questions on-topic on JL meta?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/are-what-can-i-do-to-improve-this-post-questions-on-topic-on-jl-meta)

[What can I do to improve my answer to this grammar question?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/what-can-i-do-to-improve-my-answer-to-this-grammar-question)

Cross-site related:

[Should we downvote answers to obvious duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202895/should-we-downvote-answers-to-obvious-duplicate-questions)

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions

[Answering a duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252047/answering-a-duplicate)

Answer (score 2):

I looked at all your answers and I can only find one down vote. You won't get a massive number of up votes because the community isn't that large.

I don't know why you got that down vote on the duplicate question. I can only guess that it was because you provided a lot of details that the OP probably already new, in addition to answering the question.

I've been using the site for two years and it seems to me that it takes a while for answerers to become established and trusted.

I think the best way to improve your answers is to look at how the people with the higher votes think about the questions. On the other hand, it's always good to have people describing things from different points of view.

Please don't be discouraged and please keep contributing.

Comment: `I don't know why you got that down vote on the duplicate question.` -- I suppose you're talking about this → https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/50390/9831 I'm not the downvoter but I think it was downvoted because it contains incorrect information, such as 「[はいけない (changed to はいかない)]」and 「わけにはいかない (wake ni haikanai) = [particle] strong (or "extreme") version of ーてはいけない」

Comment: @Chocolate I'm sure that ーわけにはいかない is modified form of ーてはいけない, but it may have different usage than I expected. As downvote for unknowingly answering duplicates, the discussion currently open here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project.

Comment: `ーわけにはいかない is modified form of ーてはいけない` ←　う～ん…違うと思いますね・・てかそもそも意味が違うｗ